# How can I simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(x^{2^{n-1}} + y^{2^{n-1}}) (x^{2^{n-1}} - y^{2^{n-1}})$$

I derived it like, $[(x^{2^{n-1}})^2 - (y^{2^{n-1}})^2]$ , as $(a+b) (a-b) = a^2 - b^2$

Is there any way to simplify it further?

Comment: As a first step to simplify use LaTeX to write mathematics in this site. You can find direction in the FAQ section. As it is now it's very hard to understand it...

Comment: oh, sure. I was wondering the same how I could do that.

Comment: Your formulas don't render appropriately in LaTeX because x^{2}^{n-1} is ambiguous. You should write it with an extra set of braces as x^{2^{n-1}} (rendering as $x^{{2}^{n-1}}$) if that is what you intended, or else as x^{2(n-1)} (rendered as $x^{2(n-1)}$). Which one is it?

Comment: Thanks, Harald. This is what I was looking for. =)

Comment: Why is this question tagged as "linear-algebra"?

Comment: @user1551, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(a^{2^b})^2=a^{2^{b+1}}$.

Comment: Gerry, Can you explain me how? (sorry, I am weak in math)

Comment: How can you know whether the OP meant $\,a^{2^b}\,$ or $\,\left(a^2\right)^b=a^{2b}\,$ ?

Comment: $(a^{2^b})^2=a^{2^b}\cdot a^{2^b}=a^{2^b+2^b}=a^{2\cdot2^b}=a^{2^{b+1}}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio He couldn't, but it was a (very) reasonable guess.

Comment: As @Harald wrote, or slightly more simply: ${\left(a^{2^{b}}\right)}^2 = a^{2 \cdot 2^b} = a^{2^{b+1}}$

Comment: So, you mean $(2^{2^4})^2=2^{2^{4+1}}$.?

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. I worked it out myself. Its just the same. Thank you so much once again.